# how to check if a file exists with vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have a folder with many files. It looks like this  file1.txt, newFile1.txt, file2.txt, newFile2.txt, file3.txt, newFile3.txt, file4.txt, newFile4.txt, ....

I have a code that generates the newFilei.txt . 
I want to write a vbscript that checks if a newFile exists in this folder or not. 
I tried this

```
Set objFolder = FSO.GetFolder("C:\myFolder\")

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files 
        fileName=objFile.name 
    If instr(fileName,"newFile*") =1 Then
        WScript.Echo "new File exist"
    End If
Next
```

but this didnt work. any ideas ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Edit: The COM object made this very simple.

```
Dim FSO
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fso.FileExists("C:\myFolder\newFile.txt") Then
    'Perform Code
End If
```

---

Or, if you wanted your code to work

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = FSO.GetFolder("C:\myFolder\")
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files 
        fileName=objFile.name 
    If instr(fileName,"newFile") Then
        WScript.Echo "new File found"
    End If
Next
```

---

And, pulling it all together.

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = FSO.GetFolder("C:\myFolder\")
Set objFiles = objFolder.Files 
For i=0 to objFiles.Count
    If FSO.FileExists("C:\myFolder\newFile" & i & ".txt") Then
        WScript.Echo "new File found"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: FTR, `Scripting.FileSystemObject` is a COM object. It has nothing to do with .Net.

Comment: Learn somethin' new everyday! Thanks Ansgar!