# Converting CSV to XLS doesn't work with Office 2003

Tags: excel, vbscript

While trying to run the below-mentioned script in a PC with MS Office 365, it worked fine but is giving me an error if I try to run the same script in a PC with MS Office 2003 installed.

> Windows script Host
>   Line 36
>   Char 17
>   Error SaveAs method of Workbook class failed
>   Code 800A03EC
>   Source Miscrosoft Office Excel

**Goal:** Convert all CSV files in the specified folder to XLS every one minute. As mentioned above, it works fine in a machine that has office 365 installed but is giving out an error if I run it in a machine with Office 2003 installed. they both are separate machines. Please help me solve this compatibility issue so I can run this script in a machine with MS office 2003 installed.

```
Dim waittime: waittime = 1 * 60 * 1000
'Constants
Const xlOpenXMLWorkbook = 51             '(without macro's in 2007-2016, xlsx)
Const xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled = 52 '(with or without macro's in 2007-2016, xlsm)
Const xlExcel12 = 50                     '(Excel Binary Workbook in 2007-2016 with or without macro's, xlsb)
Const xlExcel8 = 56

Do
    ' Extensions for old and new files
    strExcel = "xls"
    strCSV = "csv"

    ' Set up filesystem object for usage
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

   ' Access the folder to process
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\User\Desktop\CSV to XL")

    ' Load Excel (hidden) for conversions
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.Visible = False
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

    ' Process all files
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        ' Get full path to file
        strPath = objFile.Path
        ' Only convert CSV files
        If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(strPath)) = LCase(strCSV) Then
            ' Display to console each file being converted
            'WScript.Echo "Converting """ & strPath & """"
            ' Load CSV into Excel and save as native Excel file
            Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strPath, False, True)
            objWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(strPath, strCSV, strExcel), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            objWorkbook.Close False
            Set objWorkbook = Nothing
        End If
    Next

    WScript.Sleep (waittime)
Loop
```

Comment: how much data is in the workbook?  excel 2003 can only handle 65536 rows and 256 columns.  o365 can handle 1,048,576 rows and 16,384 columns,.

Comment: Most certainly within those numbers. Rows and columns won't be more then two digits in fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` value of the `xlFileFormat` enumeration saves the file as an Open XML Workbook *which is only supported since Office 2007*. Now, since you want to save it in an Excel 2003 file format, you should use the appropriate value for that *which, in this case, would be `xlExcel8`*.

Here's a list of all the values for the `xlFileFormat` enumeration:

[**xlFileFormat enumeration (Excel)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat).

So, what you need to do is replace `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` from your call to the `SaveAs` method with `xlExcel8`:

```
objWorkbook.SaveAs outputFilePath, xlExcel8
```

---

**Edit:**

If you only have Office 2003 installed, looks like `xlExcel8` wouldn't be supported, so you need to use `xlExcel9795` instead. First, add this constant at the top of your file:

```
Const xlExcel9795 = 43
```

Then, you can pass it to the `SaveAs` method like this:

```
objWorkbook.SaveAs outputFilePath, xlExcel9795
```

Comment: @Samarth Actually, my bad, I misunderstood your question (thought you wanted to convert from XLS to CSV, not the other way around). I've edited my answer so please let me know if there's anything not clear.

Comment: Looks like i am still doing something wrong. If you don't mind, can you please modify the code for me? So i can have a better understanding?

Comment: question 1: as per your suggestion i should add "xlExcel18" in the list of constants mentioned at the top right? What should it equal to? What exactly that value represents? So, In other words, xlExcel18 = 56, whats the meaning of 56 there?

Comment: Question 2: 

If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(strPath)) = LCase(strCSV) Then
           
            ' Load CSV into Excel and save as native Excel file
            Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strPath, False, True)
            objWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(strPath, strCSV, strExcel), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            objWorkbook.Close False
            Set objWorkbook = Nothing
        End If

should be changed to, what exactly. i have confusion regarding the syntax. If you refer to my code, my source folder is same as the destination folder.

Comment: You don't have to add it to your code because it's already there. Now, You should always read the documentation to understand how things work so let me provide you with some links: The [`SaveAs`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_RXem52kTHnoytEwPJxb8w/videos) method accepts a parameter called `FileFormat` which represnts the format that the workbook will be saved in. Now, there are many options for the format as shown [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat) with a description for each one. One of them is `xlExcel8` which represents an Excel 97-2003 Workbook.

Comment: Regarding your second question, I'm not sure I get your point but let me be as clear as possible. All you need to change in your code to make it work for Exce2003 is replace `objWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(strPath, strCSV, strExcel), xlOpenXMLWorkbook` with `objWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(strPath, strCSV, strExcel), xlExcel8`. Have you done that already?

Comment: After making suggested changes, i am still getting an error, SaveAS method of Workbook class failed

Comment: i changed extensions for old and new files from "xls" and "csv" (without a period symbol in front of it worked fine when i was using this code with MS Office 365) to ".xls" and ".csv". Now there is no more errors but code doesnt seem to convert csv files to xls yet for some reasons. any guesses?

Comment: @Samarth Try leaving the `FileFormat` parameter empty. That should work for Office 2003. So, you would be using `objWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(strPath, strCSV, strExcel)` only without the second parameter.

Comment: Thank you. It works. However, the challenge now is it will take all the comma separated data and put it in the first cell. earlier it used to keep its mapping in place while going from one format to another. in other words, When i made above mentioned changes to the script, all the data of raw A (so data of A1, A2, A3, and so on) is accumulated in A1, all the data of raw B is accumulated in B1 and so on. while data from A1 should go to A1 and data from A2 should go to A2 and so on. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @Samarth I've edited my answer. You need to add the constant `xlExcel9795` and use it instead of `xlExcel8`  like this: `objWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(strPath, strCSV, strExcel), xlExcel9795`. I tested it with Excel-2003 and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: That worked perfectly fine. Thank you so much for all your help and support.

Comment: Before concluding, One functionality i'd like to learn to add to this program to make it little smarter and i'd need your help for it. As this is in a loop, it converts all csv to excel every minute. Now i'd like to add a function which checks before converting XYZ.CSV if XYZ.XLS is already there in the folder. if it is it will exclude that file and move to next one and so on. So basically it will not keep converting all the CSV files over and over again if it is already converted once to XLS and it still exists in that folder.

Comment: @Samarth Well, that's a different question, which would normally mean that you should ask a new question. However, in this particular case, that question had been answered many times before and you should not ask a duplicate question (you should do research first). Here's a little guidance: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22387719/4934172) shows you how to check if a file already exists. Check [more results](https://www.google.com/search?q=vbscript+check+if+file+exists) if needed. Also, there are other alternatives you might consider like deleting (or moving) the converted CSV files.

Comment: I totally understand sir. The issue with the examples i found were limited up to checking a specific file. I am looking for a generic function that can check if .xls exist of the same file name before it does the conversion.

Comment: @Samarth Think about it for a second. _"check if .xls exist of the same file name"_ = _"a specific file"_. Moreover, if you expect to always find some code that you can copy and paste into your script/program and it works right away, you'll be very disappointed. When you find code that does the basic idea of what you need, you take that and _write your own solution_ based on it, you find and read the docs to help you in the process and if you still have problems, then you can ask a question providing all the info and **showing your attempts** so that someone can help you. Good luck :)